# UITableView Custom Header using a UICollectionReusableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm currently using a UICollectionReusableView to make a custom header for a tableview. The problem I'm facing is that this header is not scrolling with the tableview as I would like. Here's how I implemented the headerview:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("StoresListHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! StoresListHeaderView;

    return headerView;

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 170; 
}
```

In the UICollectionReusableView .swift file there's the default code and in the .xib just a backgroundImage.

Is there any boolean option to set this up? Otherwise what would you use?

Comment: Is your tableView.style .plain or .grouped? Grouped tableview headers don't scroll.

Comment: It was exactly that but the opposite. Grouped Scrolls, plain doesn't. Now it works! Place the answer if you want and I will validate it ;)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the correction. Glad that fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing UITableView's `style` property to `.plain` if it isn't. The `.grouped` style will keep the header on screen while scrolling.